# Treeview in vba userform

Tags: excel, vba

Need help.. i have already spent 3 days but there is no result. I am tring to pull the data (sheet1) in treeview but could not successed. Requesting all the expert to assist me.

i want the show the below data (sheet1) in treeview. When I click directory, it should show all the senion managers and when I select the particular manager, it should show the all the repective supervison belongs to that manager and when I select the particular supervisor, it whould show all the employees belongs to that supervisors.

I will be very thanksfull if someone assist me.

```
Director    Senior ManagersSupervisorName EmployeeName
AMP Diwaar  Dsameer kap
AMP Diwaar  Dsameer Danke
AMP Diwaar  Vishaws Bhagan
AMP Rohan   Sapla   Kumbar
AMP Rohan   Sapla   Dhavale
AMP Abhijit Maoj    Khalsa
AMP Abhijit hiral   Rajiwad
AMP Abhijit hiral   Shitol
AMP Chandekar Atul  Gunjal
AMP Chandekar Atul  Gundad
AMP Chandekar Gsamee    Patanwala
AMP Dhanesss     Ganes  Khan
AMP Dhanesss     Ganes  Keshari
AMP Dhanesss     suhai  Darwajka
AMP Dhanesss     suhai  Nirmale
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Nodes.Add` throws an error if we try adding a node which exists already, we can doing this as simple as follows.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 Set rTWData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D16")

 With TreeView1

  Set oNode = .Nodes.Add(, , "root", "+")
  oNode.Expanded = True

  On Error Resume Next
   For Each oRow In rTWData.Rows

    .Nodes.Add "root", tvwChild, oRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, oRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
    .Nodes.Add oRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, tvwChild, oRow.Cells(1, 2).Value, oRow.Cells(1, 2).Value
    .Nodes.Add oRow.Cells(1, 2).Value, tvwChild, oRow.Cells(1, 3).Value, oRow.Cells(1, 3).Value
    .Nodes.Add oRow.Cells(1, 3).Value, tvwChild, oRow.Cells(1, 4).Value, oRow.Cells(1, 4).Value

   Next
  On Error GoTo 0

 End With
End Sub
```

The `On Error Resume Next` will simply overstep all those nodes we trying add as duplicate.

Comment: Is it possible to show the count of employees agasint each selecttion.

Comment: Are you the same user as http://stackoverflow.com/users/5561292/gaus-shaikh? If so, why using two different accounts? Furthermore, your question is unclear. Where shall the count be displayed? As a part of the string that appears in the treeview node? If so, simply concatenate the result of a `COUNTIF` into that string.